# Why are my Angular, absolute path, URL's not compiling properly with Closure Compiler?

Tags: angularjs, google-closure-compiler

Take the following example directive:

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "/my/absolute/path.tmplt.html",
        controller: ...Do Controller Stuff...
    }
});
```

This runs through the Closure Compiler without error. However, when loading the app I am greeted with a 404 as it tries to load the full /my/absolute/path.tmplt.html path. Removing the leading '/' resolves the problem. This is also a problem for 
`ng-include(src="'/my/url'"), ng-controller="myCtrl")` located in the HTML files and I suspect anywhere you could reference a url.

So why do absolute paths fail while relative ones work just fine?

Answer (score 2):

You have an invalid path specified. If you current page is `asdf.com/boo/yourpage` try going to `asdf.com/my/absolute/path.tmplt.html` You should see a 404.

This is not really related to angular Or google closure and is related to your folder structure + your server configuration.

Comment: The templateUrl does not require a full web path. This is evident from the documentation, nor would it make since that all template requests be made from the site url. Furthermore, this approach works with or without the leading '/' until it is run through google closure.

The following show the use of ng-include and directives that reference the template html by file directory structure, not web structure.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude